# try: statement fails

Tags: python

I have some python code that fails:

```
import sys
print ("MathCheats Times-Ed by jtl999")
numbermodechoice = raw_input ("Are you using a number with a decimal? yes/no ")
if numbermodechoice == "yes":
    try:
    numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
except ValueError:
    print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
try:
    numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
except ValueError:
    print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
    numberx2 = (float)(raw_input('Enter second number: '))
elif numbermodechoice == "no":
    print ("Rember only numbers are allowed")  
    numberx1 = (int)(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
    numberx2 = (int)(raw_input('Enter second number: '))
else:
    print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
    exit()
print ("The answer was")
print numberx1*numberx2
ostype = sys.platform
if ostype == 'win32':
    raw_input ("Press enter to exit")
elif ostype == 'win64':
    raw_input ("Press enter to exit")
```

(Full code [here](http://pastie.org/1554883))

I want to wrap the float operations with try statements so if a `ValueError` happens, it gets caught.  Here is the output:

```
 File "./Timesed.py", line 23
    try:
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

What is wrong with it and how can I fix this?

Comment: @Senthil: It doesn't help if you correct the code that has the problems in it.

Comment: @S.Lott Because this new user is probably trying to learn Python, and is probably doing a lot of mistakes.

Comment: You need to provide the exact indentation for each line.  Replace all of the tab characters with 8 spaces and reproduce the exact file.  you can run python -tt on the script [if you save the text to a script] and it will tell you if you indented properly

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of the code as it is in your `Timesed.py` file.  The error that you've shown us seems to be pointing at how you indented that block of code.  There are other problems here but we'll be able to better help you if we saw everything.

Comment: I should note that I replaced originally posted code with the (trimmed) full code.  Just in you see the answers as being out of place.

Comment: There's something weird with the provided code: it does not look like the try block is improperly indented.  the numberx1 line is the one that's off

Comment: @Foo: It's exactly how jtl had written it.  You can see it in the link he added.  He must have changed it before updating the question.  If you saw the original, some of the input code as been changed.  He hasn't included the new errors since the update.

Comment: @Jeff: as the code is stated, and it looks like your response uses the same code, the try statement is properly indented.  its definitely the numberx1 statement that's off

Comment: @Foo: I'm not a mind reader and I shouldn't have to run the code to figure out what the problem is and what the error says _now_.  I can make assumptions on what it might say now, but I'm not going to put words in his mouth.  Besides the updated code and grammar fixes, it is _exactly_ as jtl posted and updated.  Yeah it's off, but that shouldn't be our problem.

Comment: @Jeff: haha didnt see the posted source :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is whitespace sensitive, with regards to the leading whitespace.

your code probably should be indented like

```
import sys
from sys import exit
print ("MathCheats Times-Ed by jtl999")
numbermodechoice = raw_input ("Are you using a number with a decimal? yes/no ")
if numbermodechoice == "yes":
    try:
        numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
        numberx2 = float(raw_input('Enter second number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
        exit()
elif numbermodechoice == "no":
    print ("Remember only numbers are allowed")  
    try:
        numberx1 = (int)(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
        numberx2 = (int)(raw_input('Enter second number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops you typed it wrong")        
        exit()
else:
    print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
    exit()
print ("The answer was") 
print numberx1*numberx2
ostype = sys.platform
if ostype == 'win32':
    raw_input ("Press enter to exit")
elif ostype == 'win64':
    raw_input ("Press enter to exit")
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, the indentation of your code is very important.  The error you've shown us points here:

```
if numbermodechoice == "yes":
    try:
    numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
except ValueError:
    print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
```

All code that is part of a block must be indented.  By starting a `try` block, the following line is part of that block and must be indented.  To fix it, indent it!

```
if numbermodechoice == "yes":
    try:
        numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Oops you typed it wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a wrong syntax. It should be `except ValueError:` and not `except: ValueError`. Correct it for you in the question too.

Comment: I think you should not edit the question that way. You should leave the wrong code in there, so that people won't be confused by your answer. Remember, when editting, you should improve formatting, improve wording... but don't change the meaning! Don't fix a broken code if the question asks why the code is broken!

Comment: @Denilson, point take and I understood the problem with editing the question like I did. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the second `print` statement.

Indentation is important in Python. It's how you delimit blocks in that language.

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to float is using an incorrect syntax. That syntax is valid for C/C++/Java, but not in Python. It should be:

```
numberx1 = float(raw_input('Enter first number: '))
```

Which will be interpreted like `float("2.3")`, which is a constructor for the `float` type being called with a string parameter. And, yes, the syntax is exactly the same for the function call, so you might even think the constructor is a function that returns an object.

Comment: Although it's not normal use of python syntax, it's still valid code (the input/conversion).  Everything here is first class so it should still be the same, even if we wrap the function names in parens.  It's just terrible style to do it this way.  Just wanted to make that distinction.

Comment: -1 In Python (and most other languages), `(expression)` and `expression` are equivalent. The conversion to float is using syntax that is unusual and happens to look like a C-etc cast, *but it's quite valid Python*, and gives exactly the same answer as removing the redundant parentheses, and is NOT the cause of the OP's problem, nor any part of it.

Comment: @John Machin, true! That's a weird syntax that looks like C, but as you say, is still valid! Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

class YesOrNo(object):
    NO_VALUES  = set(['n', 'no', 'f', 'fa', 'fal', 'fals', 'false', '0'])
    YES_VALUES = set(['y', 'ye', 'yes', 't', 'tr', 'tru', 'true', '1'])

    def __init__(self, val):
        super(YesOrNo,self).__init__()
        self.val = str(val).strip().lower()

        if self.val in self.__class__.YES_VALUES:
            self.val = True
        elif val in self.__class__.NO_VALUES:
            self.val = False
        else:
            raise ValueError('unrecognized YesOrNo value "{0}"'.format(self.val))

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.val)

def typeGetter(dataType):
    try:
        inp = raw_input
    except NameError:
        inp = input

    def getType(msg):
        while True:
            try:
                return dataType(inp(msg))
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return getType

getStr     = typeGetter(str)
getInt     = typeGetter(int)
getFloat   = typeGetter(float)
getYesOrNo = typeGetter(YesOrNo)

def main():
    print("MathCheats Times-Ed by jtl999")

    isFloat = getYesOrNo("Are you using a number with a decimal? (yes/no) ")
    get = (getInt, getFloat)[int(isFloat)]

    firstNum = get('Enter first number: ')
    secondNum = get('Enter second number: ')

    print("The answer is {0}".format(firstNum*secondNum))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
    if sys.platform in ('win32','win64'):
        getStr('Press enter to exit')
```

Comment: The OP is having trouble getting his indentation right. He thinks he needs to cast, like (float)(something). Please consider whether your answer might be way over the top.